# Como puedo recoger los datos de un formulario de preguntas select a partir de una funcion con js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formularios, html-select

```
<label for="Pregunta1">¿Siente que su familiar solicita más ayuda de la que realmente necesita?</label>
            <select id = "Pregunta1" name="Pregunta1">
                <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                <option value="2">A veces</option>
                <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
            </select>

<label for="Pregunta2">¿Siente que debido al tiempo que dedica a su familiar ya no dispone de tiempo suficiente para usted?</label>
<select id = "Pregunta2" name="Pregunta2">
                <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                <option value="2">A veces</option>
                <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
</select>
```

Las preguntas son de este tipo. Todas tienen las mismas opciones. Necesito una funcion que recoja los valores de los selects. Se como recoger el valor de un select en concreto.
Por otra he pensado en hacerlo poniendo un name generico para todos y otro para cada uno pero es extraño.

Comment: Por otra parte no se si poner que salga una pregunta por pagina y que al darle al botón de siguiente te recoja ya los valores. ¿Pero como puedo poner una pregunta por página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recoger los datos usando js, una de las opciones posibles es crear una función que es llamada por el evento onchange().

Por ejemplo:

```
<select id = "Pregunta1" name="Pregunta1" onchange="obtenerValores()">
```

Y esta función la puedes realizar así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function obtenerValores()
{
/* Para obtener el valor */
var valor= document.getElementById("Pregunta1").value;
return valor;

}
</script>
```

Si tienes muchas preguntas, puede resultar un poco pesado llamar al método varias veces, por lo que quizás te viene bien pasarle como parámetro el id.

```
function obtenerValores(identificador)
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad. Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado!!

Comment: Me alegro. Te recomiendo usar jquery. Javascript tiene un bastantes frameworks y librerías de utilidad. ¡Ánimo!

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera soalmente que en el select le ponga un onchange y llames a la funcion siempre llamaras a dicha funcion que te retornara el valor o alli guardartela en alguna variable o hacer lo que quieras.

```js
    function GetValueSelect(id){
      console.log(document.getElementById(id).value)
      return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
```

```html
   <label for="Pregunta1">¿Siente que su familiar solicita más ayuda de la que realmente necesita?</label>
                <select id = "Pregunta1" name="Pregunta1" onchange="GetValueSelect('Pregunta1')">
                    <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                    <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                    <option value="2">A veces</option>
                    <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                    <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
                </select>

    <label for="Pregunta2">¿Siente que debido al tiempo que dedica a su familiar ya no dispone de tiempo suficiente para usted?</label>
    <select id = "Pregunta2" name="Pregunta2" onchange="GetValueSelect('Pregunta2')">
                    <option value="0">Nunca</option> 
                    <option value="1">Casi nunca</option> 
                    <option value="2">A veces</option>
                    <option value="3">Bastantes veces</option>
                    <option value="4">Casi siempre</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Gracias, si puse un onchange y le pase por parametro (this.id) para que me coja el id y funciona